# Last 3 elements pushed onto next row

Tags: errors, matrices

```
$ M E^{ij} = M\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & \cdots & e_{i-1} & e_j & e_{i+1} & \cdots & e_{j-1} & e_i & e_{j+1} & \cdots & e_{m-1} & e_{m} \end{bmatrix}$
```

The rendered equation mysteriously pushes the last three elements onto a new row.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please give a minimal wording example!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If it doesn't fit the line then it breaks it. What's the problem?

Comment: @percusse It breaks it even for lines that should fit

Comment: That is very unlikely to happen if you haven't done any other setting somewhere else. That's why previous comments are asking for a minimal compilable document to reproduce it.

Comment: Put `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20} ` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AMSMath manual, bmatrix and similar support up to 10 columns as default, the example has 13 columns (and gives the classical "extra alignment tab has been changed..." error on compilation). So you get 10 columns, extra values are pushed to a new line.

Comment: @Kuttens, yes, there is.

Comment: Look up MaxMatrixCols